# How does regularization prevent overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, math, neural-network

I don't understand how adding the product of lambda and the sum of squared thetas to the cost function would decrease the amount of over fitting in a data set. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Well, looking just at the sum of squared parameters, the parameters which minimizes that is just theta = 0. If you put a factor (namely lambda) on that and add it to the ordinary sum of squares, the result you get will be somewhere between 0 and the unconstrained maximum -- lambda times sum of squared parameters acts as a penalty term which pulls the solution towards 0. The larger the value of lambda, the stronger the pull. HTH. Btw this is a great question but suitable for stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Apologize for lateness but this is a great answer! Thank you for the tip, I will try stats.stackexchange.com first next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine two extreme cases:

1. You do not need to learn anything ==> You need 0 parameters to learn (an extreme case of underfitting).
2. You want to memorize everything you see (in the training set) ==> You need a huge amount of parameters to remember everything (an extreme case of overfitting)

The real training should happen between these two cases, to lead to a good generalizations. A good generalization helps to get more realistic predictions on the unseen test data.

When you try to minimize a cost function, you are penalizing the machine for each of the wrong predictions on the training set. To overcome this penalization, and most of the time easier than getting to a real generalization, machine would prefer to memorize everything in training, so that it gets to a lower loss, and get less penalized. This easily happens when you provide a complex network( with big amount of training parameters, AKA when W is big)

To prevent this trick from the machine, we force the machine to reduce the cost, but also we put the condition to use not a very large set of parameters. That is one way to do the regularization.

Comment: Perfect answer! This has helped me understand the subject much better.